# String equality in Java using ArrayList of HashMaps? I am using .equals()

Tags: java, string, equality

I'm trying to remove items from a List of HashMaps, and when looking at the console output, it's plainly clear that the strings being compared are equal, and I am using the .equals(String x) method to compare, however the output of this continually shows false, and nothing gets removed from the list. Could anyone give me a hint as to what I'm doing wrong here?

```
public void removeWord(String wd) {
        Log.println(Log.INFO, "Initial Size", "Initial size" + String.valueOf(allWords.size()));
    for (int x = 0; x < allWords.size(); x++) {
        Log.println(Log.INFO, "Current Word", allWords.get(x).get("Long") + " " + wd);
        Log.println(Log.INFO, "Equality?", String.valueOf(allWords.get(x).get("Long").toUpperCase().equals(wd)));
        if (allWords.get(x).get("Long").toUpperCase().equals(wd)) {
            allWords.remove(x);
            Log.println(Log.INFO, "Removed something", "Removed Something!!!!");
            clearAdapter();
        }
    }
        Log.println(Log.INFO, "Size of list", "Size of list" + String.valueOf(allWords.size()));
}
```

Comment: Do the words you are comparing have some whitespace in them that you are not accounting for?  Try allWords.get(x).get("Long").toUpperCase().trim().equals(wd)

Comment: Why are you using `toUpperCase()` on one `String` and not on the other?  Can you guarantee that `wd` is always upper case?

Comment: I can't help but notice that your debug output does not include `toUpperCase();` yet your debug equals() and your if does.

Comment: Whoops, the string is trimmed and set to uppercase prior to being sent to this method, I probably should have mentioned that bit...

Comment: If you still can't find the issue, try making a for loop on both words, printing the ascii codes for each character

Comment: Arg! Thank you all for the extremely quick replies, my error was that the method was being called, then the string was trimmed, just had to swap the order of the lines...

Comment: You most likely want to change the removeWord method to include the 'equalsIgnoreCase' instead of assuming all passed in strings are already in upper case, and possibly include the trim as well.  It's not necessary as you can manipulate the passed in strings before this method (as you're doing), but it should be clear in the comments and/or method name what this method will or won't do. If another person calls the method, they may not realize it will only remove uppercase strings that have the same whitespace - this may the the desired result of your code, but it isn't clear to another person

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing the uppercase value of the String mapped to `"Long"` to the original value of `wd`. Unless `wd` is being passed in as uppercase you could be off. Try using [`equalsIgnoreCase`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase%28java.lang.String%29) and also make sure that both strings don't have leading or trailing spaces by calling [`trim`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29). I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

When you solve the problem, which may be caused by extraneous invisible characters in the string or the values - try comparing lengths in your logs as well - you should use an iterator to go over allwords and the iterator's remove method, or you may get an inconsistent iteration.